# Casting double to int like java

Tags: c#

I need some help casting a big double to int, in java:

```
(int)System.currentTimeMillis(); //result -186983989 (java)
```

The result always return the int32.minvalue, but I need the same result as java.
but in C#:

```
DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970;
Int32 resultado = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds; //result is always -2147483648 and i need same as java
```

Thanks in advance, can see this image https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pwU6fnT0v663NPqa7cSwwU9MSFQeO1TjdOdip1GFn8Eqg0Fgo_rsA3ER2jw5RDpXGOa1WiMc_PFIzzjxkqWe9zQ/wtf.png?psid=1.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Casting `System.currentTimeMillis()` to `int` doesn't do anything useful in Java. Do you really *want* the bottom 32 bits of a `long` value?

Comment: I have to migrate that java code, but in C# gives diferent result.

Comment: But what on earth are you *using* that value for? It's a pretty meaningless value. Note that it's *not* returning MinValue, which is -2,147,483,648.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The result is much larger than this. You'll need a larger data type with a larger range. Try `long` instead of `int`.

```
long resultado = (long)span.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Result:

```
resultado   1335553169530   long
```

Comment: I need to emulate a java's method, and it cast to (int) and return about -1790999999 but in C# alway return MinValue.

Comment: @user1361817: Well you *could* use `(int)(long)span.TotalMilliseconds` but it's weird to do that. It seems like your original code is buggy.

Comment: In debug mode, display the result i need, but in execution return a diferent value. :S